# How to increment value based on duplicates and grouping

Tags: excel

I have three columns, and I need column C to increment if there is a duplicate in column B, but only if the data is in the same group in column A:

```
          A                 B               C

     1  Group 1           AB123             1
     2  Group 1           SD244             1
     3  Group 1           AB123             1        * should be 2
     4  Group 2           FF444             1
     5  Group 2           CD444             1
     6  Group 3           AB123             1        * should stay as 1
     7  Group 3           AB123             1        * should be 2
```

So basically Since AB123 is found again in column B in row 3, C3 increments by one, but C6 doesn't because it's in a different group (and then C7 does again because it 's in the same group as C6).

When I use COUNTIF($B$1:B1, B1), it doesn't increment by grouping also. Anyone have any idea how do it?

**edit
got it to work: used countifs($A$1:A1, A1, $B$1:B1,B1)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you could sort it by Column A and then Column B, you could write some nested IF statements that, for C2 for example would be something along the lines of: C2 `=IF(A2=A1,IF(B2=B1,C1+1,1),1)` syntax might be slightly off, but I think that should get you close, but only if you do the double column sort, otherwise, I don't know any simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just been trying to do this in `Office 2016` with my data in the table, I found the following worked:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[[#Headers],[COLUMN1]]:[@[ COLUMN1]],[@[ COLUMN1]],Table1[[#Headers],[ COLUMN2]]:[@[ COLUMN2]],[@[ COLUMN2]])
```